# news: remove path "article" or "article detail"

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-8.x

I use TYPO3 8.7 and extension "news" version 6.1.
I want to shorten the news article detail path.
I already use this (the advanced example):

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html

Now I have:
`article/title-of-the-news/`

How to get rid of the "article" path? "article" is the title of the page where the news detail plugin is located.

Comment: At first I thought you could just hide the page via the "exclude form speaking url" checkbox in the page settings. But I don't think you can actually shorten that URL any further - that won't work, because then realurl will try to display the home page.

Answer (score 1):

There are the hooks "encodeSpURL_postProc" and "decodeSpURL_preProc" in realurl. With them you can overwrite and remove parts from your url.

I guess you use "fixedPostVars"?

Comment: yes, i use fixedPostVars

i found this example:
http://t3g.at/sprechenede-urls-eigene-extension-typo3/

Comment: with this:  

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(  
    'encodeSpURL_postProc' =>   array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),  
    'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),  
);

i manage to replace the path "artikel" with "jobs". But i didn't manage to remove it.

Comment: here is the right code for my comment above:

function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('job/', 'artikel/', $params['URL']);
}

function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref) {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace('artikel/', 'job/', $params['URL']);
}

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    'encodeSpURL_postProc' => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
    'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),
);

Answer (score 0):

Use the page, where you the news list is located, also as page for the news details. The news list will get overwritten with the news details.

I think there is no other solution, you can't have a page "article" for the news details but no part "article" in the url: TYPO3 has to know on which page it should display the news details.